# Join on hyphenated index field in Unix

Tags: unix, join, merge, awk

I'm new to Unix and am having trouble joining two tab-delimited textfiles based on an a field that has a hyphenated index. For example:

```
file1.txt
33-47   10      22      -99     10
33-48   15      22      165     456
33-101  10      22      -99     15.8
33-126  10      22      -99     15.5
34-133  10      22      -99     13
40-109  10      22      -99     12
41-102  88      21      -99     20
45-169  54      214     -99     4
100-11  652     524     87      5
101-25  45      54      153     8
101-26  1285    12      155     9.5
```

and

```
file2.txt
1       5432    545     33-101
1       5524    5420    33-126
0       855520  52220   33-47
0       5463    5420    34-133
0       5563    5423    40-109
1       6098    -99     40-109
```

Essentially, file 1 is a look-up table, and I want to append the matching line of file 1 to file 2 in order to create a full table of variables, ie:

```
file3.txt (expected)
1       5432    545     33-101  10      22      -99     15.8
1       5524    5420    33-126  10      22      -99     15.5
0       855520  52220   33-47   10      22      -99     10
0       5463    5420    34-133  10      22      -99     13
0       5563    5423    40-109  10      22      -99     12
1       6098    -99     40-109  10      22      -99     12
```

I'm using Cygwin, and have tried first sorting the fields numerically, normally, and with the LC_COLLATE=C locale, as well as a number of awk NR==FNR commands, but I still get a blank outfile.

This is all new and very frustrating. Please help if you can!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, but I'm not on Cygwin:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{info[$1]=gensub(/[^\t]*\t/,"",1)} NR!=FNR{printf"%s\t%s\n",$0,info[$NF]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

I'm sure someone can improve on that...

Comment: This is awesome and works for me. I also found that join works, but that some of my files had whitespace throwing it all off. 

If you get a second to translate I would be ever grateful!

Comment: Some explanations:
Read file1 (NR==FNR)
  Build array info. Indices are the values in 1st column (awk uses strings as indices)
  Values of array info[xx-yy] are strings = rest of line
    gensub takes the line ($0) and replaces the first string ending with tab /[^\t]*\t/ by an empty string. This removes first col. 
      3rd arg of gensub means replace only first match.
      /[^\t]*\t/ : regular expression matching many non-tab chars followed by one tab. 
Read file2 (NR!=FNR)
  $NF : last word on each line. Happens to match indices of array info.
  print line ($0), append value of info[$NF]

Answer (score 1):

I would be ***very*** interested to know how you got `join` to work.

Here is a very ugly way:

```
a='{split($f, a, /-/); $f = sprintf("%05d%05d", a[1], a[2]); print}'
join -1 4 -2 1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 0 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 \
    <(awk -v f=4 "$a" file2.txt | sort -k4,4) | 
    <(awk -v f=1 "$a" file1.txt | sort) \
    awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} {$4 = substr($4, 1, 5) + 0 "-" substr($4, 6, 5) + 0; print}'
```

Output:

```
0       855520  52220   33-47   10      22      -99     10
1       5432    545     33-101  10      22      -99     15.8
1       5524    5420    33-126  10      22      -99     15.5
0       5463    5420    34-133  10      22      -99     13
0       5563    5423    40-109  10      22      -99     12
1       6098    -99     40-109  10      22      -99     12
```

If you omitted the `-o` output specification (and change the field from `$4` to `$1` in the final `awk`), thus shortening the command, this is what the output would look like (common field first):

```
33-47   0       855520  52220   10      22      -99     10
33-101  1       5432    545     10      22      -99     15.8
33-126  1       5524    5420    10      22      -99     15.5
34-133  0       5463    5420    10      22      -99     13
40-109  0       5563    5423    10      22      -99     12
40-109  1       6098    -99     10      22      -99     12
```

The above works by left-padding the numbers in the key field and removing the hyphen, then later undoing that. This allows a simple lexical sort.

I was tempted to use `sort -V` (version sort) instead of using the padding technique. It gives the correct sort order, but `join` disagrees.